# click back and forth through the slideshow

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysqli

this is so that when you start to picture 1 so that when the switch on the picture 2 then you can say "click" on it so that you can go back to frame 1 of the present that you have to wait more 10 pictures before it comes again but you can just click back to it.

the problem is right now: I must have done so that you can click back and forth through the "pictures" that is, one is in photo 3 and would like to return to picture 1 then you can make it through to click back.

I try to google around to do so you can just click on the picture then you come back and forth.

Here is my code which I will show you:

Php/mysqli

```
echo "<div id=\"slideshow\">";
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT navn, title FROM slideshow ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")) { 
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($navn, $title);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<div>
        <img src=\"/indhold/img/tilbage.png\" id=\"tilbage\">
        <h3>$title</h3>
        <img src=\"/indhold/img/$navn\" alt=\"$title\" title=\"$title\">
        <img src=\"/indhold/img/frem.png\" id=\"frem\">
        </div>";
        }

        /* Luk statement */
        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃÂ¦ringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

css code here:

```
#slideshow {
    width: 708px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
    min-height: 99px;
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;

}
#slideshow > div h3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px;
    padding: 11px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 97%;
    background-color: #002855;
}
#slideshow > div #tilbage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    bottom: 35px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#slideshow > div #frem {
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    bottom: 35px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

jquery code here:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
            setInterval(function() { 
              $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            },  9500);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner when it comes to jQuery but I used this code to create my image scroller so to speak. I use a previous and next button to scroll through my images:

javascript:

```
  <script>
  var init = function () {
      var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel222'),
          navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#navigationcaro222 button'),
          panelCount = carousel.children.length,
          transformProp = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
          theta = 0,

          onNavButtonClick = function (event) {
              var increment = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-increment'));
              theta += (360 / panelCount) * increment * -1;
              carousel.style[transformProp] = 'translateZ( -182px ) rotateY(' + theta + 'deg)';
          };

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          navButtons[i].addEventListener('click', onNavButtonClick, false);
      }

  };

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Then for the HTML part I used:

```
 <p id="navigationcaro222" style="padding-left:80px">
 <button id="previous2" data-increment="-1">Previous</button>
 <button id="next2" data-increment="1">Next</button>
```

Hope this helps.